# Mongrel_rails can't find memcache-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, memcached, mongrel

We started to use memcache-client in our rails app and it works just fine with "script/server" but "mongrel_rails start" fails with an error.

In environment.rb we define "memcache-client" and version "1.8.1". Gem list shows that the gem is installed: memcache-client (1.8.1).

If run with "script/server" everything works but with "mongrel_rails start" it fails with error:
no such file to load -- memcache-client

Any advice what could be wrong here? Is there something different in the way mongrel_rails loads the gems compared to script/server? Or is my setup just broken?

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring it as "memcache" instead of memcache-client.